Looking for proteins play role in cardiovascular diseases (disease ontology)
I'm looking for proteins that (probaly) play role in cardiovascular diseases. I have to do a list about them. It's recommended to use The Disease Ontology. But if I'm correct this specific protein informations is not imported in the database.  Could you suggest a right method to use Disease Ontology for this purpose? Or do you know any other tool or database or idea that applicable?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

This question seems too general to produce useful answers. Bioinformatics Stack Exchange works best with specific bioinformatics problems rather than general discussion. For that, I recommend posting on another site that is more discussion based, like reddit.

cross posted: https://www.biostars.org/p/9602811/

cross posted: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/115404/looking-for-proteins-play-role-in-cardiovascular-diseases-disease-ontology
